# Converting NetCDF to GRIB2

Tags: python, netcdf, grib, cdo-climate

I know there is software like [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) that will convert files in `grib` and `grib2` format to `NetCDF` files, but I need to go the other way: from `NetCDF` to `grib2`, because the local weather offices here can only consume gridded data in `grib2` format.

It appears that one solution could be in Python, using the [NetCDF4-Python library](http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/) (or other) to read the `NetCDF` files and using [pygrib](http://code.google.com/p/pygrib/) to write `grib2`.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some more research, I ended up using the British Met Office "Iris" package (http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/index.html) which can read NetCDF as well as OPeNDAP, GRIB and several other formats, and allows to save as NetCDF or GRIB.

Basically the code looks like:

```
import iris

cubes = iris.load('input.nc')       # each variable in the netcdf file is a cube
iris.save(cubes[0],'output.grib2')  # save a specific variable to grib
```

But if your netcdf file doesn't contain sufficient metadata, you may need to add it, which you can also do with Iris.  Here's a full working example:

https://github.com/rsignell-usgs/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/files/Iris_CFSR_wave_wind.ipynb

Answer (score 5):

I know CDO is mentioned in one of the other answers, but I thought it would be useful to give the full command, you need `copy` and you specify the output format with the -f option

```
cdo -f grb2 copy in.nc out.grb
```

Answer (score 4):

One can also use climate data operators (cdo's) for the task -https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/wiki

but need to install the software with all additional libraries.

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty extensive. Have you ever used it to convert NetCDF4 to GRIB2?

Comment: This is indeed THE best way to do it. When dealing with netCDF files, sooner or later CDO and/or NCO will be very useful. They are fast and reliable, they keep metadata, they are free and extremely versatile. Once you have learned CDO and NCO well any manipulation on gridded files can be performed. The two are by far the most complete solutions for working with gridded files without needing to code (R, Python are more versatile but usually slower).

Comment: In reply to Rich, GRIB2 output is possible by using the -f grb2 flag, see below for full command

Answer (score -1):

ECMWF has a command line based tool to do just this: https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/grib_to_netcdf

Comment: the question was about netcdf to grib, not grib to netcdf

Comment: True, but N1B4 is correct to point out that ECMWF has a neat toolset for handling grib/netcdf, although I believe grib_api has just been superseded again.